# VBA: Is it possible to make objects that were declared and instantiated in a single line "Nothing"?

Tags: vba

The following code declares and instantiates an object in a single line, then tries to set it to Nothing

```
Dim myObject As New MyClass
Set myObject = Nothing
MsgBox (myObject Is Nothing) 'FALSE
```

The message of the third line is "False". However, if I split the declaration and instantiation into two lines, like so:

```
Dim myObject As MyClass
Set myObject = New MyClass
Set myObject = Nothing
MsgBox (myObject Is Nothing) 'TRUE
```

Suddenly the message is "True". I have a lot of objects I've already declared and instantiated in one line, that may need to be made Nothing. Is there any way to do this without changing all the declarations?

Also, if anybody can explain why this is so, I'd appreciate it. I'm self-taught at VBA and don't really understand the language... it's very strange compared to my usual languages..

Comment: See note here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx on "auto-instancing" variables

Comment: Implicit type conversions and automatic initialisations have subtleties of consequence that are diabolical to debug. C-derived languages are popular precisely because they *don't* try to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the reference variable in **Locals window**, that should explain it to you. The problem, as mentioned before is that due to `Dim ... As New ...` **myObject** reference variable is assigned to an object in your msgbox statement. If you afterwards set it to nothing it will be nothing again.